# How to move a sprite who runs along a straight line by pressing on the left and right keys of the keyboard in Rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I want to move a sprite (runner) by pressing  the left and right arrow keys of the keyboard:
The idea is to move a small character who runs along a straight line by pressing  on the left and right keys of the keyboard...
this is the link to download the html page:
blob:http://jeanferdysusini.free.fr/b502274c-88d4-48e6-87ce-fbc29b93e63d

The code should be in rxjs.

this is what I've done so far  (***Thank you for your help***):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>TP RXJS</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js">
  </script>
  <style>
#screen{
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid black;
  width:300px;
  height:250px;
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Cours !  Cours ! Forest ...</h1>
<canvas id="screen" width="400" height="400"/>
  <script>
let screen = document.getElementById('screen');
let ctx = screen.getContext('2d');
const sprite_width=84
var runner = {
  x: 0
, y: 200
, pos:0
, mode:1
, img: new Image()
, draw: function(){
    ctx.clearRect(10, 10, 400, 400);
    switch(this.mode){
      case 1:{
        ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.pos, 0, sprite_width, 100, this.x, this.y, sprite_width, 100);
        this.pos += sprite_width;
        this.pos %= sprite_width*6;
    break;
        }
      case 2:{
        ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.pos, 160, sprite_width, 100, this.x, this.y, sprite_width, 100);
        this.pos += sprite_width;
        this.pos %= sprite_width*2;
    break;
        }
      }
    }
  };
runner.img.src ="http://jeanferdysusini.free.fr/images/png/runner.png";
const code_touches = [
  "ArrowLeft"
, "ArrowRight"
  ];

let musique = new Audio('http://jeanferdysusini.free.fr/FF_vic.mp3');

// Zone à compléter : Javascript/RxJS ici

let onload = rxjs.fromEvent(window,'load' );
onload.subscribe(x=> runner.draw() );

let clavier = rxjs.fromEvent(document,'keydown').pipe(rxjs.operators.map(e => code_touches)); 
  
  let timer_jeu = rxjs.timer(0, 100).pipe(
      rxjs.operators.take(5));
  
let key  = rxjs.merge(
  clavier.subscribe(x=> timer_jeu.subscribe(x=> runner.draw())) ).pipe(
  rxjs.operators.map(e => e.key_code));

   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to move the sprite `left` when left arrow is pressed and `right` when right arrow is pressed ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I want is that the sprite moves when pressing either left or right. I want to merge this 2 events and make the sprite moving right.

Comment: Please add .html to the downloaded file: blob:http://jeanferdysusini.free.fr/b502274c-88d4-48e6-87ce-fbc29b93e63d

Comment: I posted the answer. If you are good with my answer, please accept it.

Comment: Hi bharat1226, Thank you very much for your answer, I accepted it. I have a last question, I need an observable that catches the event of crossing the finish line by the runner in position x=300 and y = 200. Thank you so much

Comment: Did you try with fromEvent ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know how to do it. I posted a new question in the link : *** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703912/rxjs-javascript-how-to-catch-the-event-of-crossing-the-finish-line-by-a-running  *** . I would be grateful if you give me an answer. I need it before midnight. Thank you  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use `tap` operator to perform side effects. And don't forget to `unsubscribe`.

```
// Zone à compléter : Javascript/RxJS ici

const { filter, first, map, mergeMap, take, tap, windowCount } = rxjs.operators;

// Initial page load event

let onload = rxjs.fromEvent(window, 'load').pipe(
  take(1),
  tap(_ => runner.draw())
);

onload.subscribe();


// Key Down observable

let keyDown$ = rxjs.fromEvent(document, 'keydown');

// Filtres key down events by code_touches ( left arrow or right arrow )

let clavier = keyDown$.pipe(filter(event => code_touches.includes(event.code)));

let timer_jeu = rxjs.timer(0, 100).pipe(take(5));

let key$ = clavier.pipe(
  mergeMap(event =>
    timer_jeu.pipe(
      tap(_ => runner.draw()),
      map(_ => event)
    )
  ),
  windowCount(5),
  mergeMap(events$ => events$.pipe(first()))
);

key$.subscribe(console.log);
```

Piped `windowCount(5)` and  `mergeMap(events$ => events$.pipe(first()))` takes 5 events and emit only one event

Comment: Thank you very much, I've been searching for ages... You solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Last question, I need an observable that catches the event of crossing   the finish line by the runner in position x=300. Thank you so much.